# Gauss-Zeidel method returns wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a code that solves system of equations with Gauss-Zeidel method. The result is incorrect, however I have no idea why. What may be the problem?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.matrix([[10, 3, 0], 
               [3, 15, 1], 
               [0, 1, 7]]).astype(float)
f = np.matrix([2, 12, 5]).astype(float)
f = np.reshape(f, (3, 1))
x_new = np.matrix([0, 0, 0]).astype(float)
x_new = np.reshape(x_new, (3, 1))
N = 100
D = np.matrix(np.zeros(A.shape))
for n in range(A.shape[0]):
    D[n, n] = A[n, n]
A1 = np.tril(A, -1)
A2 = np.triu(A, 1)
D_inv = np.linalg.inv(D)
x = np.matrix([0, 0, 0]).astype(float)
x = np.reshape(x, (3, 1))
eps = 1e-5
dim = len(A)

def gauss_zeidel(x):
    i = 0
    t = 0
    s1 = 0
    s2 = 0
    while t <= N:
        x_new = np.copy(x)
        for i in range(dim):
            print("--new cycle--")
            print("===============================")
            for j in range (i-1):
                s1 += A[i,j] * x_new.item(j)
            for j  in range(i+1, dim):
                s2 += A[i,j] * x.item(j)
            print("iteration result")
            x_new.itemset(i, (f.item(i) - s1 - s2)/A[i,i])
            print((x.item(i)), i)
        print(t)
        print("===============================")
        x = x_new
        t+=1
    print(x)
```

Comment: What are the results that you got and expected? How does the residual error fall during the iteration?

Answer (score 1):

Two errors (besides being very inefficient, since the point of numpy is to never iterate yourself arrays. But I take that this has a pedagogical purpose. I am pretty sure numpy or scipy system solving already use Gauss-Seidel when suited, unless they use better methods; but faster)

1. You set s1 and s2 to 0 only once. Obviously the two for loops are supposed to compute Σ₁ⁱ⁻¹  aᵢⱼ.xᵏ⁺¹ⱼ, and Σᵢ₊₁ⁿ aᵢⱼxᵏⱼ. So s1 and s2 should be set to 0 just before those loops. Other wise, what you are counting is this sum plus the previous result.
   So

```py
            s1 = 0
            s2 = 0
            for j in range (i-1):
                s1 += A[i,j] * x_new.item(j)
            for j  in range(i+1, dim):
                s2 += A[i,j] * x.item(j)
```

2. I've just used the same 1-based counting (saying sum from 1 to n) as you did, and as is usually used in maths and most description of Gauss-Seidel algorithm. But numpy is 0-based index. And `range` exclude the upper bound.
   Which is easier to read, contrarily to what beginners think: it means that `range(a,b)` iterates exactly `b-a` items. And that `range(a,c)` then `range(c,b)` iterates all items from a to b once and only once (including c, which is iterated in second range, not first).
   And that means that when your s1 is computed from `range(i-1)` (implicitly `range(0,i-1)` and s2 from `range(i+1,dim)`, both s1 and s2 are made of `i-1+n-(i+1) = n-2` iterations. When you know that it should be `n-1` (everything but the diagonal element). Since between `i-1` and `i+1` there are 2 elements, you are not skipping only 1 diagonal element between s1 and s2.

So, long story short, first `range` should be `range(i)` (meaning "from 0 included to i excluded", or "from 0 to i-1")

```py
            s1 = 0
            s2 = 0
            for j in range (i):
                s1 += A[i,j] * x_new.item(j)
            for j  in range(i+1, dim):
                s2 += A[i,j] * x.item(j)
```

With these 2 modifications (s1=0, s2=0; and range(i) instead of range(i-1)), result is correct.

Of course there are many possible optimization.

Just a few of them

```py
D = np.matrix(np.zeros(A.shape))
for n in range(A.shape[0]):
    D[n, n] = A[n, n]
# could be replaced by
D = np.diag(np.diag(A))
```

```
s1=0
for j in range (i):
    s1 += A[i,j] * x_new.item(j)
# could be replaced by 
s1=sum(A[i,j]*x_new.item(j) for j in range(i))

# or better, provided that you use `array` instead of `matrix` everywhere
# (matrix means that in remains 2D, even when you extract a single line)
s1=(A[i,:i]*x_new[:i,0]).sum()

# Likewise
s2=(A[i,i+1:])*x[i+1:,0].sum()
```

Comment: Regarding what SciPy actually does, the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve.html) says ?GESV from LAPACK is used for generic solves (there are other routines for symmetric, Hermetian, and positive definite). ?GESV seems to use LU-decomposition, as per the [LAPACK documentation](https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html).